# Thoughts on YSlow Feedback

Tags: performance

I have read many articles on improving the page load for Drupal and used as many steps as possible to enhance the speed of the site.

I installed the FireFox pluggin YSlow to get feedback on my site.  I scored a 91 with an A rating thanks to the changes recommended in the forum.

YSlow is giving me an Grade F on Configure entity tags (ETags) and Grade F on Use cookie-free domains.

Are ETags and Cookie-Free domains, something I should concern myself with?

Even though I have a good rating, I still feel the home page loads slowly.  Even going from a page with images to a text only page there is a delay.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your using multiple web servers then ETags need to be configured correctly. Add this to your .htaccess file (at the bottom) if this is the case. If you only have 1 server then you can safely ignore this recommendation.

```
FileETag MTime Size
```

Cookie-free domains offer a slight performance improvement because less data will be traveling over the wire. You need a CDN to get a cookie-free domain setup correctly.

Comment: I actually gave a talk on this subject; slides are at the bottom. http://pnwdrupalsummit.org/sessions/front-end-performance